# How do I wire a Shure WL 185 to an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: resistors, audio, microphone, iphone, ipad

I have this old but very nice mic. Old days I recorded audio to the camera or recorder. Nowadays I record to iPhone so I do not have extra recording device and cameras are action cameras usually without 3.5 mm jack.

What I want to do now is to resolder the plug. But I am not sure do I need to add 4.7 kΩ resistor or not? Or even will it work at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work just fine because it's a condenser microphone.

A picture should be worth 1000 words:

[image]

Comment: So should I add .05uF condenser or condenser on the scheme is one in mic? I have this adapter

https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1.E45KXXXXXbAXFXXq6xXFXXXm/-font-b-3-5mm-b-font-Stereo-font-b-Splitter-b-font-Audio-Male-to.jpg

But it does not work with it. Although I can see resistor in the jack.

Comment: I've got an answer from Sure tech support.

sorry but the mic is made to work on a mixing desk or a wireless System. These devices provide Phantom Power (48V@Mixing Desk / 5V@Wireless System).
Because a smartphone only Provides 2,7 Volts I don't think that it will work.

Comment: If you must use it purchase a pre-amp. The signal levels are very low.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone already has a preamp in it. The phone also has a resistor to a mic power supply voltage and a capacitor in it. The Shure WL185 is an electret condenser mic that is powered through its mic connection to your phone. The Gnd on the plug is the ground for the earphones and for the mic shield in the cable.

The mic connection does not want a resistor to ground or the capacitor.

You do not need an adapter, instead you need the 4 poles plug, a 3-wire cable for the earphones and a 1 wire with shield cable for the mic.